# how to view only a particular portion of a desktop website in my android app

Tags: android, web-applications

I have a desktop website in which i have many contents , but i want to show only particular part of my website in the app, and remove all of the unwanted contents .Is there any way i could do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the different site design for that. You can take the example  facebook.com and m.facebook.com open both urls from you mobile browser and you will get the difference..
database will be same for both